# Проблемы с отправкой POST запроса с помощью cURL

Tags: php, json, post, curl

Пытаюсь отправить вот такой `POST` запрос:

```json
POST /prozone HTTP/1.1
Host: 185.47.152.162:82
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: delivermore/2.0.51 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)
Accept-Language: ru-BY;q=1, en-BY;q=0.9
Content-Length: 76
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

{
  "answer_id" : 177,
  "session_id" : "токен"
}
```

С помощью вот такого кода:

```php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://185.47.152.162:82/prozone");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "answer_id=177&session_id=токен");  //Post Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
    'Accept: */*',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: ru-BY;q=1, en-BY;q=0.9',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Host: 185.47.152.162:82',
    'Connection: keep-alive', 
    'User-Agent: delivermore/2.0.51 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)',
    'Content-Length: 76'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

print  $server_output ;
```

В ответ пришла такая строка и я не знаю, выполнилась отправка или нет, и что пришло в этом ответе:

> ��VJ-*�/R��V*.I,)-V�2�QJ�OIU�212�Q�M-.NL�+�J+ �kkp�|   :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас конфликт с кодировкой. Необходимо задать явно возвращаемую кодировку.

Например: `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8`

Но вам лучше удостовериться какая кодировка используется на внешнем api, а какая на машине с php-скриптом. И исходя из этого указать нужную кодировку, либо результат вручную обработать.

Comment: На машине UTF-8, насчет внешнего api не знаю. А как обработать вручную?

Comment: Определить можно с помощью [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php). А конвертировать с помощью [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Comment: mb_detect_encoding указывает UTF-8, это значит сервер отправляет такие непонятные байты?

Comment: Отправил через postman твой запрос получил в ответ `{
    "error": {
        "status": 1,
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Такого пользователя не существует!"
    }
}`

Comment: Именно такой он и должен быть, а мне приходит вот такая непонятная строчка символов

Comment: Проблема тогда на стороне php скрипта. Попробуй снова задать кодировку ОС и выполнить перезагрузку. Если не получиться, попробуй сделать над текстом reload(это не конвертация) в другие кодировки с помощью текстового редактора

Comment: Решил проблему, она была в gzip сжатии.

Comment: Как вы отправляли запрос? Я как только ни пытался отправлять, всегда приходит `{"error":{"status":1,"code":422,"message":"Syntax error"}}`

Comment: Через postman на `http://185.47.152.162:82/prozone POST` с телом запроса `{
  "answer_id" : 177,
  "session_id" : "токен"
}`  и заголовком `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Странно. Никак вообще. Может проблемы с формированием POST?